# Passing Array data using SESSION

Tags: arrays, session

I am trying to pass a Single/Multi Dimensional array to a second page using SESSION. I read and tried all questions and answers but can not get it done. Here is the 1st page:

```
<?php
// SendIt.php
SESSION_START();
$iA=array('A1','A2','B2','B1','B3','A3');
print_r($iA);
$_session['iA'] = $iA;
echo '<br><a href="GetIt.php">Click to send the array.</a>';
?>
```

Here is the 2nd Page:

```
<?php
// GetIt.php
SESSION_START();
$iB = $_SESSION['iA'];
print_r($iB);
echo 'I am Here...';
?>
```

I do not get any of the iA array in the second page.
I must be missing something simple. Please check it out. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a different PHP forum site and was advised that: Like any other PHP variable, _SESSION is case sensitive. So the problem is fixed by matching _SESSION variables and making them all upper case.